# System Notes old value is x% greater or lesser than new value

Tags: formula, netsuite, saved-searches

I'm trying to create a saved search that compares the old value vs the new value of a specific system notes field. Basically, I want to be able to search on if a Freight Cost new value is greater than or equal to 150% of the old value. I have some questions:

1. What formula type should I be using, `Formula(text)` or `Formula(numeric)`?
2. How do I narrow down that I was a specific field of the system notes?
3. You can see my example below, where am I going wrong with the formula? or how would you write it?

Excuse the poor format but I'm going to write it how I would think it should be (aside from question #2) but it's obviously wrong since it doesn't work.

```
CASE WHEN {systemnotes.newvalue} >= ({systemnotes.oldvalue} * 1.5)
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Do you want to return only the rows where the new value is 1.5x the old value or do you want all records but show a different value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want this on the Criteria tab of the saved search:

1. It doesn't matter if you use formula text or numeric, but text might
   be more intuitive.
2. make a criteria for System Notes Fields: Field, anyof, Freight Cost
3. make a criteria for formula(Text), is, 'Applies'; with formula:

CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER(NVL({systemnotes.newvalue},0)) >= (TO_NUMBER(NVL({systemnotes.oldvalue},0)) * 1.5) THEN 'Applies' ELSE 'Nope' END

Comment: Thank you very much, for whatever reason my brain had crapped out and I just couldn't think by the end of the day. Your suggestion worked perfectly.